# Unreal Engine 5 - SkeletonMesh ignores vehiclemesh collision

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I have been trying for the past 2 days to get my robot to lift another item.
I use this robot: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/fab-digital-2023-benjamin-de-la-cerda-1d2822fe34e14891b05403b9d26f7dbb

I created a BluePrint for my vehicle (using the chaosvehicle plugin)
Added that robot in 3 parts: Body & bolts & Scoop. The body is the VehicleMesh and the bolts & scoop is a skeletal mesh.

The scoop is connected from a bolt to the body.
I rotate the bolt so that the scoop lifts.
The scoop also has a physics asset and a skeleton.
I enabled all the collision parameters on the skeleton, the scoop goes right through walls (and the standard UE5 car)
I enable the 'emulate physics' button, and now my scoop isnt attached to the bolt anymore but instead hits the bot and then flies away.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]